# JQ Select Objects Where Value Contains String And Value Not Null

Tags: json, select, null, jq

Trying to select objects from JSON array where value contains a string and value is not null.

Desired output:

```
    {
      "configurable": false,
      "property_reference": ".properties.blobstore_certificate",
      "property_type": "rsa_cert_credentials",
      "product_guid": "p-blah-29d4678e926cf2069871",
      "location": "ops_manager",
      "variable_path": "something",
      "issuer": "/C=US/O=Blah",
      "valid_from": "2019-01-16T19:55:11Z",
      "valid_until": "2021-01-16T19:55:11Z"
    }
```

When selecting from:

```
{
  "certificates": [
    {
      "configurable": false,
      "property_reference": ".properties.director_ssl",
      "property_type": "rsa_cert_credentials",
      "product_guid": "p-blah-29d4678e926cf2069871",
      "location": "ops_manager",
      "variable_path": null,
      "issuer": "/C=US/O=Blah",
      "valid_from": "2019-01-16T19:55:10Z",
      "valid_until": "2021-01-16T19:55:10Z"
    },
    {
      "configurable": false,
      "property_reference": ".properties.uaa_ssl",
      "property_type": "rsa_cert_credentials",
      "product_guid": "p-blah-29d4678e926cf2069871",
      "location": "ops_manager",
      "variable_path": null,
      "issuer": "/C=US/O=Blah",
      "valid_from": "2019-01-16T19:55:10Z",
      "valid_until": "2021-01-16T19:55:10Z"
    },
    {
      "configurable": false,
      "property_reference": ".properties.blobstore_certificate",
      "property_type": "rsa_cert_credentials",
      "product_guid": "p-blah-29d4678e926cf2069871",
      "location": "ops_manager",
      "variable_path": "something",
      "issuer": "/C=US/O=Blah",
      "valid_from": "2019-01-16T19:55:11Z",
      "valid_until": "2021-01-16T19:55:11Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

Using:

```
curl blah | jq ' .certificates[] | select(.variable_path|test("thing"))'
```

Getting:

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:0): null (null) cannot be matched, as it is not a string
```

I think the issue is that there are nulls. I am not sure how to select with the presence of these nulls without getting the error.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

One way to remove the `null` values from consideration would be:

```
.certificates[] | select(.variable_path | strings | test("thing"))
```

You could also consider using `?`, which could be used here like this:

```
.certificates[] | select(.variable_path | test("thing")?)
```

Comment: If I just use `| strings` it returns the object that has the string, but the pipe to the test doesn't seem to work, so I get no output.

Comment: I've double checked.  Have you miscopied or misplaced the parentheses?  Have you tried both solutions?